# I'd like to have a button for Modal form on React-Select NoOptionsMessage

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-select

So, I have a searchable Select, and my goal is to let users add new item if and only no options left. That's why I wanted the button to appear on NoOptionsMessage.

const NoOptionsMessage = (props) => {
return (
<components.NoOptionsMessage {...props}>
<MultiDialog
title={title}
description={desc}
content={}
onSave={doSave("MultiDialog doSave fired")}
>

</components.NoOptionsMessage>
);
};

So, NoOptionsMessage I have onSave fired and my Modal doesn't open onClick.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57npj.png)

Of course, the goal is quite the contrary ))).

Any help will be appreciated).

The link is here
https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-fast-gdvgdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try lifting your open state up from `MultiDialog`.
When you click on button that is inside `MultiDiaog` that is child of `NoSelectMessage` component it is behaving like you are selecting an option and when option is selected then `NoSelectMessage` component and `MultiDialog` is unmounting.

Here is working code:

```
function SelectBoxNoOptionButton({
  rows,
  onChange,
  value,
  isClearable,
  isDisabled,
  isMulti,
  isSearchable,
  desc,
  defaultValue,
  btnCaption
}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); // create state outside Multidialog
  const options = rows || [];

  const defValue =
    options && value ? options.find((c) => c.value === value) : "";

  const NoOptionsMessage = (props) => {
    return (
      <components.NoOptionsMessage {...props}>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            setOpen(true); // update state on click
          }}
        >
          Добавить клиента
        </Button> // use button instead of Multidialog
      </components.NoOptionsMessage>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      <MultiDialog
        open={open}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false);
        }}
        title={desc}
        description={desc}
        content={<CustomerAddEdit customer={defaultValue} />}
        doSave={doSave("MultiDialog doSave fired")}
      ></MultiDialog> // use it outside NoSelectMessage so it won't unmount on option select

      <InputLabel shrink htmlFor={desc} sx={{ mb: -1, mt: 1, mx: 1 }}>
        {desc}
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        options={options}
        value={defValue}
        onChange={(val) => onChange(val.value)}
        isLoading={!rows}
        isDisabled={isDisabled || false}
        isMulti={isMulti || false}
        isSearchable={isSearchable || false}
        isClearable={isClearable || false}
        closeMenuOnSelect
        fullWidth
        placeholder="Выбор..."
        components={{ NoOptionsMessage }}
        styles={{ noOptionsMessage: (base) => ({ ...base, ...msgStyles }) }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export { SelectBoxNoOptionButton };
```

MultiDialog:

```
const MultiDialog = (props) => {
  const { title, description, content, doSave, open, onClose } = props;

  const onSave = () => {
    doSave();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose}>
        <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>{description}</DialogContentText>
          {content}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={onClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={onSave}>Save</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
};
export { MultiDialog };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Sk, really appreciate your help. Actually, I do not have enough reputation to upvote, so, just thanks.

Comment: @Y.G. If the answer solves your problem, you can "accept" it by pressing the checkmark under the +/- buttons (it will turn green). This lets other viewers know that the solution in the answer works, and also gives +15 to the poster of the answer.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck, thanks, done ).